# AWS Elastic Search Policy, only allow lambda to access Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, aws-elasticsearch

I'm  working on setting up an `ElasticSearch` instance on `AWS`. My goal is to only allow http request from my `Lambda` function to the `ElasticSearch` instance. I have created one policy, that gives the 'Lambda`access to the`ElasticSearch`instance. The part I'm struggling with is the inline resource policy for`ElasticSearch`that will deny all other request that aren't from the 'Lambda`.

I have tried setting the `ElasticSearch` resource policy to `Deny` all request and then giving my `Lambda` a role with access to `ElasticSearch.` While the `Lambda` is using that role I am signing my http requests using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) but the request are rejected with `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.` I don't think the issue is the actual signing of the request but instead the polices I created. If anyone can steer me in the right direction that would really help.

`Lambda Policy`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:ESHttpGet",
                "es:CreateElasticsearchDomain",
                "es:DescribeElasticsearchDomainConfig",
                "es:ListTags",
                "es:ESHttpDelete",
                "es:GetUpgradeHistory",
                "es:AddTags",
                "es:ESHttpHead",
                "es:RemoveTags",
                "es:DeleteElasticsearchDomain",
                "es:DescribeElasticsearchDomain",
                "es:UpgradeElasticsearchDomain",
                "es:ESHttpPost",
                "es:UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig",
                "es:GetUpgradeStatus",
                "es:ESHttpPut"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:,accountid>:domain/<es-instance>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:PurchaseReservedElasticsearchInstance",
                "es:DeleteElasticsearchServiceRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

`ElasticSearch Inline Policy`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:<account-number>:domain/<es-instance>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

`Lambda Code Using Aws4 and Axios`

```
//process.env.HOST = search-<es-instance>-<es-id>.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
function createRecipesIndex(url, resolve, reject){

         axios(aws4.sign({
            host: process.env.HOST,
            method: "PUT",
            url: "https://" + process.env.HOST,
            path: '/recipes/',
       }))
      .then(response => {
          console.log("----- SUCCESS INDEX CREATED -----");
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log("----- FAILED TO CREATE INDEX -----");
        console.log(error);
        reject();
      });
}
```

Note: I have tried creating my index with the inline policy on `ElasticSearch` set to allow *(all) and removing the `aws4` library signature and it works fine. Right now I just want to secure access to this resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue and it was 2 fold. The first issue was my inline `resource policy` on my `ElasticSearch` instance. I needed to update it to allow the role that I have given to my `Lambda`. This was done by getting the `role arn` from `IAM` and then creating the below policy to be attached inline on the `ElasticSearch` instance.

My second issue was with `aws4`. the `path` and the `url` I set did not match. My path had `/xxxx/` while my url was `https://search-<es-instance>-<es-id>.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/xxxx`. Since the `path` contained an extra forward slash not found in the `url`, the signing failed. For anyone else using the library make sure those values are consistent. I hope this helps someone else out in the future :D

`Elastic Search Policy`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/service-role/<role-name>"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:<account-id>:domain/<es-instance>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```